# Passing more parameters to Action Efficient?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Action callback called `Action<GameObject,GameState,GameObject,Vector3> onCutCB;`
I have 5 Scripts that references a function called

```
void OnCut(GameObject survivalObj,GameState state,GameObject 
    destroyObj,Vector3 startPos){
    ////
}
```

but the problem is that out of these 5 scripts ,first scripts need 3 parameter,second script need all parameters ,rest of the scripts need one parameter
So the question is
1) should i use callback or call the functions manually from by using the reference of the respective classes
2) As i am passing 4 parameters out of which some parameters  are useful in some scripts  will there be more garbage collection ? than calling the scripts method manually ?
Out of the four parameters i passed 2 are reference type and 2 are value types.

Comment: Measure it and decide for your specific case. Anyway, micro-optimizations are evil in 99% of cases. Especially when you're deciding on a  OnGameOver function which will most likely occur only once and not 1000 times per second...

Comment: OnGameOver callback is being called 5 times per minute,actually i have just replace the name to OnGameOver

Comment: One session in your game lasts 12 seconds? Why do you call OnGameOver 5 times each minute?? Anyway, why exactly are you trying to optimize this? Are you facing any problems? If yes, it would be more beneficial to focus on them instead of a micro-optimization.

Comment: OnGameOver  is not actually OnGameOver but something other ,i just used that as an example , though when i was playing my game on mobile devices til  to  minitues it works fine but after that some times its lags a bit I am using object pooling also when i restart the game my scene doesnt load i just use pooling because the gameobject which were instantiated were required,I just wanted to know that using callback is useful or should i call amnually to every script

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem here. I'm afraid we can't help you with this description... You're probably experiencing some kind of memory leak and I don't believe it's caused by passing more parameters to a function, but it's pretty much impossible for us to debug this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) should i use callback or call the functions manually from by using
>   the reference of the respective classes

Calling functions directly is faster but this shouldn't be a problem at all. It doesn't make that much difference.

> 2) As i am passing 4 parameters out of which some parameters are
>   useful in some scripts will there be more garbage collection ? than
>   calling the scripts method manually ? Out of the four parameters i
>   passed 2 are reference type and 2 are value types.

No, there will be no memory allocation when you pass more parameter to a delegate. The only time memory will be allocated is when you initialize the `onCutCB` variable. For example, `onCutCB = OnCut;`. That's why `onCutCB` must be initialized in the `Start` or `Awake` function once. When `onCutCB` in invoked, memory allocation does not happen.

Read the comments in the code below to see where memory is allocation or not:

```
Action<GameObject, GameState, GameObject, Vector3> onCutCB;

void OnCut(GameObject survivalObj, GameState state, GameObject
destroyObj, Vector3 startPos = default(Vector3))
{

}

void Start()
{
    //MEMORY IS ALLOCATION
    onCutCB = OnCut;
}

void Update()
{
    //NO MEMORY ALLOCATION HERE
    onCutCB(objToUse, gameState, anotherObj, thePos);
}
```

> though when i was playing my game on mobile devices til to minitues it
>   works fine but after that some times its lags a bit I am using object
>   pooling also when i restart the game my scene doesnt load i just use
>   pooling because the gameobject which were instantiated were required.

This problem you described has nothing to do with the gradual slow-down of your game. You are either instantiating many Objects non-stop, starting a coroutine every frame from the `Update` function and coroutine does not end/stop or something that adds up to the execution time.

Without your *all* scripts, it is impossible to tell what's causing your problem. Please, do **not** edit your question with all your code. Find and fix the problem yourself.

**Use the Profiler!**

Go to *Windows* --> *Profiler* then enable *Deep Profiler* and click on "Record" and clicl the Play button. You will see which script is allocating memory and how much time it takes for each function to complete. Look into these and fix it.

[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/profiler-overview-beginners) is a full Unity tutorial on how to use the Profiler.

Comment: Yes , i have used profiler , but in profiler my cpu time never goes above 30%, playing game like 10-15 min works fine but the problem arises later that too for few seconds on mobile devices  . On Unity editor its not lagging even for 20 minutes .(the mobile i used is Nexus 5). And thanks for the memorry allocation of callbacks i wasn't knowing that